# How can I check the verbatim characters of a bash command string?

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I had this strange behavior this morning in a bash terminal :

```
user@home:/home/user$ [ -f /etc/openvpn/client.conf ] && echo true
bash: [: missing «]»
user@home:/home/user$ [ -f /etc/openvpn/client.conf ] && echo true
true
```

- The first command was **pasted** from a script edited with gedit.
- The second was **typed directly** in the terminal.

After some digging, I find out that **removing the 30th character** (the space between client.conf and "]") and replacing it with a space made the command work again.

My assumption was right : **an unknown blank character has slipped into the command**, but the question is :

1. How can I reveal those characters in the terminal so that I can debug the command? And more important:
2. How can I prevent this from happening again?

*BTW, I running Ubuntu 18.04 / French language, the script that I paste the command from is in a USB drive and may have been edited on Windows too.*

---

Thank you for your very good answers.
The bad character is a **c2 a0** non-breaking space UTF-8 character. The question [How to remove special 'M-BM-' character with sed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357248/how-to-remove-special-m-bm-character-with-sed) has interesting fact about that character.

The strange thing is that the script is free of this character. So I don't know where it came from.

Comment: Use an editor that highlights such characters. Syntax highlighting helps a lot, too. Never paste directly from the web to the terminal, always go through the aforementioned editor.

Comment: Yo might want to find the problem command in your history list, then pipe the output through a hex display program. So that you don't need to wade through a long listing, either rerun the command to place it at the bottom of the history list and run `history 2|xxd` (because the `history` command itself is always the last in the list), or type `history|grep "CommandWithProblem"|xxd`. You can use any other hex display program instead of `xxd`, but this defaults to a format I like.

Comment: @Gabriel Glenn, please mark the best / most helpful / whatever answer as "_accepted_" using the tick - rather than commenting on each that the answer helped. [info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/364309)

Comment: @Attie, Yes I will, I just usually wait 24 hours before accepting the best answers, as suggested in : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Personally I'd use `set -x`. This would show you the command & how it's split. It wouldn't necessarily say "bad character here", but it would show you that bash wasn't splitting on that character.

Comment: @Patrick Good suggestion! Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option is to look at the characters you're trying to use with a hex viewer or editor. `hexdump` is a good option if you are limited to the terminal.

```
$ hexdump -Cv <<"EOF"
> [ -f /etc/openvpn/client.conf ] && echo true
> EOF
00000000  5b 20 2d 66 20 2f 65 74  63 2f 6f 70 65 6e 76 70  |[ -f /etc/openvp|
00000010  6e 2f 63 6c 69 65 6e 74  2e 63 6f 6e 66 20 5d 20  |n/client.conf ] |
00000020  26 26 20 65 63 68 6f 20  74 72 75 65 0a           |&& echo true.|
0000002d
```

You can see here that the `space`, `close-square-brace`, `space` are correct - `0x20`, `0x5D`, `0x20`.

These values are ASCII codes, displayed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). Any value outside the range `0x20` - `0x7E` is not a ["*printable character*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) as far as ASCII is concerned, and most likely won't play well with command line interfaces.

*Note:* I copied your first "*broken*" line for use in the `hexdump` example above, so something has replaced the *not-an-ASCII-space* with an ASCII space between your original source and your rendered question.

---

To repeat this, take the following steps:

1. Type `hexdump -Cv <<"EOF"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Paste the text you would like to use
3. Type `EOF` on a line of its own, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Terminals and Command Line Interfaces don't handle special characters well - as you have discovered. If you aren't very careful with formatting documents, you will also have problems with Microsoft Word (and others) using "*smart quotes*", em-dashes, the list goes on...

Spot the difference: (the top is "*smart quotes*", the bottom is "*straight quotes*")

[image: example of smart quotes vs straight quotes]

```
$ hexdump -Cv <<"EOF"
> “quoted string”
> EOF
00000000  e2 80 9c 71 75 6f 74 65  64 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67  |...quoted string|
00000010  e2 80 9d 0a                                       |....|
00000014
```

Here, the open quotes are not a simple ASCII quote (`"`), but are a Unicode / [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) series - `0xE2`, `0x80`, `0x9C`, or [`U+201C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Unicode_symbols) - which the terminal will not handle as you might expect.

Kiwy's suggestion of `cat -A` also does the job:

```
$ cat -A <<"EOF"
> “quoted string”
> EOF
M-bM-^@M-^\quoted stringM-bM-^@M-^]$
```

---

***Note:*** when using `echo "..." | hd`, you stand a chance that bash will substitute parts of the string you are trying to inspect. This is particularly of concern when trying to inspect components of a script.

For example try:

```
$ echo "${USER}"
attie

$ echo "`whoami`"
attie

$ echo "$(whoami)"
attie

$ cat <<EOF
> ${USER}
> EOF
attie
```

These methods are replacing components with the relevant text. To avoid this, use one of the following approaches. Note the use of single quotes (`'`), and a ["*quoted heredoc*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) (`"EOF"`).

```
$ echo '${USER}'
${USER}

$ echo '`whoami`'
`whoami`

$ echo '$(whoami)'
$(whoami)

$ cat <<"EOF"
> ${USER}
> EOF
${USER}
```

Comment: This solution works : `echo "[ -f /etc/openvpn.ovpn ]" | hd  ` returns `[...] c2 a0 [...]`. We can see the *c2 a0* UT-8 character _non-breaking space_

Answer (score 18):

You could use `cat` with the `-A` option: from the manual:

```
   -A, --show-all
          equivalent to -vET
   -E, --show-ends
          display $ at end of each line
   -T, --show-tabs
          display TAB characters as ^I
   -v, --show-nonprinting
          use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

So `cat -A yourscrip.sh` will show you invisible and strange characters.

Comment: This solution works : `echo "[ -f /etc/openvpn.ovpn ]" | cat -A` returns `[ -f /etc/openvpn/client.ovpnM-BM- ]$`. We can see the *M-BM-* UT-8 character _non-breaking space_

Comment: @GabrielGlenn glad this helped you.

Answer (score 9):

`echo "<your command>" | hd` should work. Look for backspace (0x08) or characters with codes >=80. `echo "<your command>" | wc -b` and checking that the count matches what you see is also a good idea.

Copying stuff from files produced by anything with "Office" in its name is dangerous, because such software often takes the liberty to replace characters:  in French, look out for double quotes replaced by "guillemets", in English for plain quotes replaced by their open/close equivalents. The hardest one I ever found was a 0-width non-breaking space in the middle of a file name (3 days of server downtime...).

Comment: It's worth mentioning `hd` is short for `hexdump` which is also mentioned in Attie's answer.

Comment: @MikaelKjær - On Ubuntu, `hd` is equivalent to `hexdump -C`.

Comment: @xenoid : I said 'edited on Windows', not edited with a Office Writer, we are not crazy ;). If it was edited, it was with Notepad++.

Comment: This solution works : `echo "[ -f /etc/openvpn.ovpn ]" | hd  ` returns `[...] c2 a0 [...]`. We can see the *c2 a0* UT-8 character _non-breaking space_

Answer (score 2):

Bash, and other shells like zsh, can open the current command line in an editor. The default shortcut for bash is `C-x C-e` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>), and it opens in the first available of  `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR` and emacs. In practice this is invaluable for debugging and modifying complex commands. Depending on how you look at it, zsh is more friendly than bash here: when the editor exits, bash runs the command immediately, whereas zsh waits for you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (giving you more chances to edit the command).

After opening the command in an editor, you can configure your editors to show non-ASCII characters differently.

For example, [with Vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159484/70524), using these settings:

```
set encoding=latin1
set isprint=
set display+=uhex
```

[image]

Or, adapting the other answers' methods:

```
bash-4.4$ f() { cat -A "$@"; false; }   # exit false to prevent bash from running the command
bash-4.4$ VISUAL=f
bash-4.4$ [ -f /etc/openvpn/client.conf ] && echo true  # C-x C-e here
[ -f /etc/openvpn/client.confM-BM- ] && echo true$
```